Mac: Unable to install pyzmq and tokenizers in virtual environment
I can install them in the global environment, but I kept getting error messages when trying to install them in the virtual environment. (I'm a mac user).
Part of the messages are:
  × Building wheel for pyzmq (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [310 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/j6/qs5r3__d7jx5yy10bhfgbb9w0000gn/T/pip-build-env-6jec4y8_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
...
9 warnings and 7 errors generated.
      ************************************************
      ************************************************
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
Failed to build pyzmq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I checked my clang, and it's fine?
Fthe or tokenizer, it sathe ys Rust compiler is missing, but why I can download it in the global environment?
I've added these to the activate file, zeromq has also been installed.
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
